# How to prevent Content-Type header from being added by web servers

Tags: php, apache, nginx, iis, lighttpd

I have a PHP script setting the Content-Type header to an empty value:

```
header('Content-Type: ');
```

This prevents nginx and Apache2 from setting the header, but the PHP development server sends the header even though it is empty.

I would like to know the best way to prevent this header from being added by web servers when the body of the response message is empty.

Thank you!

Comment: So your question is actually about the PHP development server, rather than all the other ones you tagged? Or have you experienced this isue on others too?

Comment: The other servers should be able to still set it

Comment: The question is figuring out the best way on these servers. If it's possible to do it in PHP, that would be great. On the PHP development server, for example, it sets the header to an empty value and that makes Firefox crash. Nginx and Apache2 strip the header. I would like to know how to prevent the header from being set on other servers.

Comment: Does your problem have anything to do with IIS?

Comment: I would like to know if setting the header to an empty value also causes IIS to remove it, not sending it to the client.

Comment: Tested: apache, lighttpd and nginx remove headers set with an empty value.

Comment: Overwrite the “Server” header using the IIS Manager HTTP Response Headers or URL Rewrite modules. Both of these modules can be used to set the server header to a custom or blank value, however will not remove it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [header_remove](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php)?

```php
header_remove('Content-Type');
```

Comment: This causes PHP to not send the header. But, the server adds 'Content-Type: html; charset=UTF-8'. I don't want him to add this.

Comment: The servers: apache and nginx.

Comment: "This causes PHP to not send the header. But, the server adds 'Content-Type: html; charset=UTF-8'. I don't want him to add this."  Then configure apache, nginx, or lighttpd to not add Content-Type to responses from your PHP.  Your PHP can then send Content-Type, or omit it.  lighttpd will not sent Content-Type to the client if the PHP sends a Content-Type response header with a blank value.  Alternatively, apache, nginx, and lighttpd support NPH (non-parsed headers) sent from the backend (e.g. CGI or FastCGI) PHP process.